# Why second call to receive doesn't retrieve a message in Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm playing with processes in Erlang and trying to create a simple counter process.
It receives a PID of a sender, increments inner counter and sends new counter value to the sender.
I'm launching my code from **erl** shell (Erlang/OTP 20, Eshell V9.2).
And I'm able to successfully receive first reply from the counter process, but not the second.

```erlang
%% Process function that serves as a counter
CounterFun = fun() ->
  (fun Receiver(Current) ->
    io:format("  -- Entering receiver, current ~p~n", [Current]),
    receive
      Sender ->
        New = Current + 1,
        io:format("  -- Sending ~p to ~p~n", [New, Sender]),
        Sender ! New,
        Receiver(New)
    end
  end)(0)
end.

CounterPid = spawn(CounterFun).

CounterPid ! self().
receive V -> V after 3000 -> timeout end. % Will provide 1

CounterPid ! self().
receive V -> V after 3000 -> timeout end. % Will result in timeout
```

Here how it looks like in my console.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first receive binds the variable `V` to `1`, so the second receive becomes:

```
receive 
    1 -> ...

end
```

And, because the message `1` never arrives, the second receive times out.  After the timeout, you can call `flush()` in the shell, and you will see that there was a message `2` in the mailbox.  You can also call `b()` at any time to display the current variables and their values (which are known as bindings)--try that after executing the first receive.

In your function, you are also doing a recursive receive within a receive within a receive such that the first receive never ends.  To prove that, you can put a print statement after:

```
Receiver(New)
```

like:

```
io:format("receive ending with Current= ~w~n", [Current])
```

and you will never see any output.  You should change your receive to something like this:

```
New = Currrent + 1
receive
  Sender ->
    io:format("  -- Sending ~p to ~p~n", [New, Sender]),
    Sender ! New,
    io:format("receive ending with Current= ~w~n", [Current])
end,
counter(New).
```